# YouTube subscription layout preference not saving

Tags: youtube

My subscription page layout preferences are not saving. I prefer to have my subscription page layout as list instead of grid. Now I have to manually click the list option each time I visit the subscriptions page.

This issue began to occur about a month ago after I had wiped and reinstalled macOS. Prior to wiping, I never had any issues.

My work laptop which is also a Mac does not have this issue, and my personal Windows PC does not have this issue either.

I've found a few mentions of it on Google with no real answers. I could bookmark the site with the query params */subscriptions?/flow=2* but then each time I click the subscription button in the sidebar it goes to */feed/subscriptions* which then goes back to the grid layout.

This problem is reproducible in multiple browsers. I am completely at a loss of what the cause could be and I'm looking for some ideas from the community on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

#### There can be several reasons for this.

### The Most likely:

Make sure **you are not** blocking neither 3rd party nor 1st party cookies on YouTube.

Cookies are used to save a bunch of settings in your Browser. Stuff regarding your YouTube account. Which is also a Google account.

Cookies are issued by YouTube's parent company ABC(Google), which is seen as a 3rd party by blockers due to YouTube being a completely different domain if compared with google.com (i.e. not a sub-domain).

Disable blocking of cookies and restart your browser, then save your settings again...

Now leave cookies enabled for YouTube or your settings will go nye-bye again.

Comment: I think it was a YouTube version problem. Today it suddenly started to remember the subscription layout. I did see that the version has updated and I am now using `release_version": "youtube.player.web_20221213_01_RC00"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was related to YouTube themselves.

I had tried several things by clearing YouTube specific cookies, ensuring cookies were allowed, etc.

The previous YouTube version was `youtube.player.web_202211xx_01_RC00`, upon getting a new version which was updated to `youtube.player.web_20221213_01_RC00` the issue had resolved.